# Render video to specific region in a canvas

Tags: wpf, video, wpf-controls, media-player, render

I created my own canvas (the black area) on which I draw element that are not derived from Shape. Instead I draw using the DrawingContext in overriden method Canvas.OnRender.

The problem is, that I want to play a video file and render the frames into a specific region (for example the red rectangle) of my canvas - also in OnRender. But usually the MediaPlayer is directly bound to a brush which fills the complete background of an UIElement.

Any help?

[image]

Okay, here some more explanation. I can scroll, pan and zoom my canvas in any direction which then effects the content that I draw in OnRender using the drawingContext. The following picture shows a canvas with an image (the door) that comes frame by frame from a webcam. Therefore I can use the BitmapSource within drawingContext.DrawImage whenever my canvas is invalidated. And I can still draw my primitives. The problem with the MediaPlayer/MediaElement is that I don't get it frame by frame but still I want to render it similar to the webcam image within my canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to achieve that. You simply need a MediaPlayer and feed it into drawingContext.DrawVideo in each Canvas.OnRender loop. Sample picture and code below. I also included methods to capture a frame (BitmapSource) from the video and also how to convert that into an old System.Drawing.Bitmap).

```
public partial class RenderCanvas : UserControl
{
    readonly MediaPlayer player;

    public RenderCanvas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Open(new Uri(@"test.avi", UriKind.Relative));
        player.Play();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        if (player != null && player.Source != null)
            drawingContext.DrawVideo(player, new Rect(0, 0, 200, 150));

        // draw any shape in front of the video
        drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5), new Point(150, 150), 60, 60);
    }

    BitmapSource GetBitmapSourceFromVideo()
    {
        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(player.NaturalVideoWidth, player.NaturalVideoHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawVideo(player, new Rect(0, 0, player.NaturalVideoWidth, player.NaturalVideoHeight));
        }

        renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        return renderTargetBitmap;
    }

    System.Drawing.Bitmap GetBitmapFromVideo()
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = GetBitmapSourceFromVideo();

        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the XAML code of the sample application. The XAML of the RenderCanvas has no changes.

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasTest_OnRender.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:CanvasTest_OnRender="clr-namespace:CanvasTest_OnRender" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <CanvasTest_OnRender:RenderCanvas />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: User drawn ellipse in front of video]

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply Clip to your Canvas, like this:

```
<Canvas Width="800" Height="600" Background="Black">
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,10,10" />
             <!-- whatever you want -->    
    </Canvas.Clip>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? The Canvas.Clip makes the canvas just smaller. I need the video to be included directly in the canvas as a shape or something similar.

Comment: It works that way - your canvas being draw in full size. Then clipping mask is applied, and makes canvas invisible outside the geometry, defined in Clip property. So, it ain't making your canvas smaller, it shows only part defined by Clip. Try different geometry and placement to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah. I understood that. But my complete drawing is on the canvas, so I can not clip parts away. I just need to add the video onto the canvas. And some shapes must be visible in front of the video.

Comment: Then why you cant put your canvas with video into usual canvas, along with any shapes you need? And it'll better if your clarify your question.

Comment: Because my canvas is drawn in OnRender using the DrawContext and not using shapes. If I put another canvas into my canvas, this would be in front of my drawing hiding everything else.

Comment: You get it in reverse. I assume you put _your_ canvas *into* normal one. So your canvas will be in front of usual one.

Comment: Then my canvas needs a transparent background so that the video which is played on the background canvas shines through. But still I can not position the video wherever I want.

Comment: Please, rewrite your question from scracth, I'm totally lost.

Comment: done, see comments and second screenshot in the original post above

Answer (score 0):

I want to playback both video ( with audio) playback via memory stream, does this code helps?

Comment: It’s a while ago, but I guess it doesn’t solve your problem. My code is rendering the picture onto a drawing canvas. So it’s about the video image. But I guess there is a callback for audio too.